# FDQUERY em tempo de execução

Tags: delphi, firedac

Estou tentando utilizar o `FDQuery` somente em tempo de execução. Já pesquisei bastante e tentei varias mudanças, porém todas elas termina com `Access Violetion`, então assim sendo suspeito que o componente não está sendo instanciado corretamente. Procurei exemplos na internet pra estudar e entender meu erro, e até esse momento não achei nada que já não fiz.

Deixo aqui meu exemplo de como o código está agora, e peço por favor que alguém aponte onde está errado.

```
private
  { Private declarations }


public
  { Public declarations }
  FDInsertForn : TFDQuery;
end;

implementation

procedure TFLancamento.EdRazaoExit(Sender: TObject);
const
SQLInsert : String =  'INSERT INTO FOR1A' + sLineBreak +
                                   '( CNPJ,FANTASIA,RAZAO)VALUES' + sLineBreak +
                                   '( :CN, :FANTASIA, :RAZAO)';
begin
  FDInsertForn.Connection:= UDM.FDConexao;
  FDInsertForn.SQL.Clear;
  FDInsertForn.SQL.Add(SQLInsert);
  FDInsertForn.Params.ParamByName('CN').AsString:= dado;
  FDInsertForn.Params.ParamByName('FANTASIA').AsString:= EdFantasia.Text;
  FDInsertForn.Params.ParamByName('RAZAO').AsString:= EdRazao.Text;
  FDInsertForn.ExecSQL; 
end;
```

Comment: Em que linha da o erro? Qual o erro?

Comment: Da erro desde a primeira linha. Cheguei a comentar do `Params` e fazer um Debug com Break Point mas assim que a primeira linha inicia já vem o access violetion.

Comment: Então provavelmente seu `FDQuery` não está criado, tente adicionar esta linha `FDInsertForn := TFDQuery.Create(nil);` antes de `FDInsertForn.Connection:= UDM.FDConexao;`

Comment: O problema foi resolvido, procurei esse exemplo que me deu e nem na documentação oficial da Embarcadeiro tem essa citação

Comment: Adicionei a resposta, com alguns detalhes a mais também.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este problema muito provavelmente ocorre porque o seu `FDInsertForn` não esta sendo instanciado. Apenas adicionar a instanciação seu problema será resolvido:

```
FDInsertForn := TFDQuery.Create(nil);
```

Mas neste código existem outros pontos a serem comentados, como você esta criando o seu `TFDQuery` em tempo de execução, não é necessário declará-lo no formulário se somente será utilizado em uma função, por exemplo:

```
procedure TFLancamento.EdRazaoExit(Sender: TObject);
const
  SQLInsert : String =  'INSERT INTO FOR1A' + sLineBreak +
                                   '( CNPJ,FANTASIA,RAZAO)VALUES' + sLineBreak +
                                   '( :CN, :FANTASIA, :RAZAO)';
var
  FDInsertForn : TFDQuery;
begin
  FDInsertForn := TFDQuery.Create(nil);
  FDInsertForn.Connection:= UDM.FDConexao;
  FDInsertForn.SQL.Clear;
  FDInsertForn.SQL.Add(SQLInsert);
  FDInsertForn.Params.ParamByName('CN').AsString:= dado;
  FDInsertForn.Params.ParamByName('FANTASIA').AsString:= EdFantasia.Text;
  FDInsertForn.Params.ParamByName('RAZAO').AsString:= EdRazao.Text;
  FDInsertForn.ExecSQL; 
end;
```

Porém, desta forma ainda existe um problema, porque estamos criando um objeto e não estamos destruindo, o ideal fazer isso com o `try` e `finally`

```
procedure TFLancamento.EdRazaoExit(Sender: TObject);
const
  SQLInsert : String =  'INSERT INTO FOR1A' + sLineBreak +
                                   '( CNPJ,FANTASIA,RAZAO)VALUES' + sLineBreak +
                                   '( :CN, :FANTASIA, :RAZAO)';
var
  FDInsertForn : TFDQuery;
begin
  FDInsertForn := TFDQuery.Create(nil);
  try
    FDInsertForn.Connection:= UDM.FDConexao;
    FDInsertForn.SQL.Clear;
    FDInsertForn.SQL.Add(SQLInsert);
    FDInsertForn.Params.ParamByName('CN').AsString:= dado;
    FDInsertForn.Params.ParamByName('FANTASIA').AsString:= EdFantasia.Text;
    FDInsertForn.Params.ParamByName('RAZAO').AsString:= EdRazao.Text;
    FDInsertForn.ExecSQL;
  finally
    FDInsertForn.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Desta forma que fizemos a cima, o objeto será instanciado na primeira linha. Se durante o processo do bloco `try` ocorrer um erro ou se der tudo certo, o bloco `finally` será executado e então o objeto será destruído.